# How to convert a counter collection into a list

Tags: python, list, counter

I need to convert a the output of a counter collection into a list

My counter output is:

```
Counter({2017: 102, 2018: 95, 2015: 87,})
```

I want to convert this into something like this:

```
[[year,count],[year,count],[year,count]]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use Counter(...).items()

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter({2017: 102, 2018: 95, 2015: 87})

print(cnt.items())
>>> dict_items([(2017, 102), (2018, 95), (2015, 87)])
```

your can convert this to the format you wanted:

```
your_list = [list(i) for i in cnt.items()]

print(your_list)
>>> [[2017, 102], [2018, 95], [2015, 87]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `most_common()` method of `Counter` to turn out a list of tuples showing values together

```
c = Counter({2017: 102, 2018: 95, 2015: 87,})
m = c.most_common()
print(m)

>>> [(2017, 102), (2018, 95), (2015, 87)]
```

You can convert the result to a list of lists instead of tuples by doing this:

```
print([list(i) for i in c.items()])
```

Answer (score -1):

In this example I wanted to covert mis collection into a list and then into a df so I did this

```
lista_conteos = [list(i) for i in n_palabra.items()]
palabras = []
conteos = []
for i in range(0, len(lista_conteos)):
    palabras.append(lista_conteos[i][0][0])
    conteos.append(lista_conteos[i][1])
```